# What algorithm is randperm based on?

Tags: matlab, shuffle

Where can I find what algorithm Matlab's `randperm` function uses? Is it Fisher-yates (Knuth) shuffling algorithm or something else?

Comment: An improved version of this question is better suited for [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: A small test in Matlab 2012b in the range of 10^5 to 10^8 shows that the calculation time increases roughly linear to the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MATLAB releases as early as R2009b, `randperm` is implemented as follows:

```
function p = randperm(n)
    [ignore, p] = sort(rand(1, n));
```

You can see it for yourself by typing:

```
type randperm
```

Basically `randperm` generates *n* numbers and sorts them, returning the resulting array of ordered indices `p` as the random permutation. The time complexity for this is *O*(*n*log*n*) at best, worse than [Fisher-and-Yates' shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), which runs at *O*(*n*).

**EDIT:** Dennis points out that in later releases `randperm` runs at *O*(*n*) time, so obviously it's improved. However, it's a built-in function so it is impossible to see its implementation.

Comment: wow. doing a poor job at mathworks?

Comment: @Shai Don't want any fingerpointing, but it seems so... –

Comment: Actually I just see this when using `type randperm` on 2012b `'randperm' is a built-in function.` When looking at the other documentation I also don't really see this being described anywhere (though it is mentioned that rand is used).

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Interesting. For R2009b it's still an m-file :)

Comment: @EitanT My guess is that they now improved more than just the file security. Quick benchmark shows approximally `O(n)` performance.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Thanks. I'll note that in my answer.