# Can only see comments for built in MATLAB files

Tags: built-in, matlab

So, this has never happened before, but for some reason, I am unable to view a default MATLAB file. That is, a *.m file that comes with your MATLAB program, (for example 'fft', 'transpose', 'angle', etc).

For example, if I wanted to inspect how the inverse tangent was being computed, all I would do was:

```
open atan
```

Right now however, all I get is a *.m file with nothing but comments in it about the file, but no actual code.

What is going on?? I have MATLAB 2013a. I have never seen this before. Why cant I inspect how MATLAB is running certain commands?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that in more recent versions the source of more functions is protected. An example is in the comments of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16421120/983722

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is common, for instance try `edit sum`, you will not be able to see the code.

When referring to MATLAB **built-in** functions it's usually meant exactly those functions whose implementation is not carried out with MATLAB language but embedded into the 
program. Built-in functions are part of TMW know-how and therefore unavailable to the general user.

The .m file is simply for the documentation.

Comment: Ah - ok, I guess I have been confusing 'built-in' functions with other types. What do we call functions that are used by ML but are implemented by m-code?

Comment: I call them simply MATLAB functions, but often built-in is used.

Comment: Ugh, Ok, I see now. >< Thanks for that!

Comment: I think the correct definition would be: built-in functions = everything that comes shipped with matlab (both plain m-code functions as well as compiled functions). Everything else you added yourself is just an ordinary m-function/p-function/compiled function/... You can test if a function is built-in using `exist('funtobetested','builtin')`. If it returns `5`, the function is built-in.

Comment: @GuntherStruyf The contradictions arise from documentation incoherence. The function `exist()` defines everything as built-in. However, if you scroll to the end of the help in the code of `meshgrid` you will not find the word built-in as you would within `sum`, although both are shipped by MATLAB. I prefer to be able to directly identify the compiled functions with built-in because for me it usually implies that they are faster but no code to read. I also prefer built-in for compiled only because of the semantics.

Comment: @OlegKomarov Then I would think you're using the word built-in incorrectly, imo you have to take it literally (as the `exists` function also does). A better word for the functions you're describing imo would be _internal_. But yeah, I see what you mean with that discrepancy. No real documentation on that either

Comment: @GuntherStruyf Semantically, built-in is taking it literally, i.e. functions which are embedded into the MATLAB engine, not shipped with.

Comment: ....So...what is the consensus about terminology for files that are as .m files, and files than are not from MATLAB?